# Obtaining Prior Record Values Using Asynchronous Flows

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, after-trigger

I created a flow that launched asynchronously and leverage the prior record values.

**{!$Record__Prior}**

The flow was unable to launch because I was referencing the prior record.

So what I did was remove the {!$Record__Prior} variable from the flow and leveraged the formula values "PRIORVALUE".

I am trying to understand why PRIORVALUE is an acceptable workaround for launching the flow in an asynchronous context when effectively {!$Record__Prior} and PRIORVALUE() are doing the exact same thing.

My fear is that there is a "gotcha" that I am not thinking abount and I want to see what the community has to say about why this may or may not be an acceptable path for me to take.

Comment: My solution for these situations is to fire a Platform event from Flow and pass Prior and Current record as Json data stream to it. And then listen for Platform Event in separate flow. This becomes Async operation and I get values both ways.

Comment: @VarunC This makes alot of sense - I am just a little bit lost on the JSON data stream? How does this work in practive?

Answer (score 5):

As of the time of this answer, you cannot use PRIORVALUE or $Record__Prior in an Asynchronous Path and see the values before the path executes. This is being considered for Run Asynchronously, but not for Scheduled Paths.

If you need to check what the prior value was, you need to make separate arrangements for this, such as saving the previous value in a different field or record. This [question](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000CfN3QSAV) has an answer that explains it:

> ... If you want to access data from a different path, you will need to save that data into the triggering record, or another record location.  We do not currently support the ability to cache values in Flow and then maintain them separately from the database for record-triggers.  We are looking at adding some more support for $Record__Prior in a future version for Run Asynchronously, but have no plans to support it for Scheduled Paths, since those are often run many months or years in the future.  In that case, the best mechanism for storing information long-term in the system is to store it in within records.

Comment: Are you confirming that PRIORVALUE() does not work in an asynchronous context?

Comment: @MatthewMetros Exactly. It will compile, but the values will appear to be the same every time.

Comment: @sfdxfox - How could Prior value not work, but ISCHANGED does work? ISCHANGED also references the prior record.

Comment: @MatthewMetros As far as I'm aware, ISCHANGED will always return false in the scheduled path, same as PRIORVALUE returning the current value. These formula functions are only meant to work in the current DML transaction, not against a past transaction that happened an arbitrary amount of time ago.